# How to import data from folder to Hive with new columns as file's name and folder's name?

Tags: hiveql

I have data input like this:

- Drivers

  - driver_1

    - 1.csv
    - 2.csv
    - ...
  - driver_2

    - 1.csv
    - 2.csv
    - ...
  - ...

Structure of csv file is:

```
x,y
0.0,0.0
18.6,-11.1
36.1,-21.9
53.7,-32.6
70.1,-42.8
86.5,-52.6
```

I want to load all file in this folder to Hive table like:

```
id, x, y, file_name, folder_name
1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.csv, driver_1
...
```

How can I do it?
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive has a [virtual column](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns) named `INPUT__FILE__NAME` that contains the full path to the input file that contained the record. Then using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` we can extract out the parent directory and the filename:

```
SELECT
    x
  , y
  , REGEXP_EXTRACT(INPUT__FILE__NAME, '.*/(.*)/(.*)', 2) AS file_name
  , REGEXP_EXTRACT(INPUT__FILE__NAME, '.*/(.*)/(.*)', 1) AS folder_name
FROM
    table
;
```